# How can I monitor QProcess finished() in qt4 (Signal/Slot)

Tags: c++, qt4, signals-slots

It looks as if their was a solution for this in qt3, but I cannot find one for qt4 (all I have used, goggling I saw solutions for qt3).

```
connect(r, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardError()), this, SLOT(updateError()));
connect(r, SIGNAL(readyReadStandardOutput()), this, SLOT(updateText()));
connect(r, SIGNAL(finished(int exitcode)), this, SLOT(updateExit()));
```

I have my stdout/stderr SIGNAL/SLOT's working just fine, but I cannot seem to find a good solution for finished.  I cannot do anything in a loop or proc->waitforfinished because I need constant updated to my UI.  How can I do this?

My error: Object::connect: No such signal QProcess::finished(int exitcode)

Thanks

Below are the SIGNALS for QProcess....

```
Signals
void    error ( QProcess::ProcessError error )
void    finished ( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus )
void    readyReadStandardError ()
void    readyReadStandardOutput ()
void    started ()
void    stateChanged ( QProcess::ProcessState newState )
```

Comment: Is your environment set up correctly for QT4?  finished is definitely a "signal" member of QProcess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

replace your code line

```
connect(r, SIGNAL(finished(int exitcode)), this, SLOT(updateExit()));
```

with

```
connect(r, SIGNAL(finished(int)), this, SLOT(updateExit()));
```

When connection signals and slots dont give a parameter name.

Answer (score 0):

I feel like I'm missing something here, but I have a few minutes... :)

What's wrong with the finished signal in 4.x?  It just adds a few parameters to what you have from what I can tell.

4.5:

```
void QProcess::finished( int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus )
```

4.0:

```
void QProcess::finished( int exitCode )
```

Change your slot to have the correct arguments and just ignore them if you don't need them.

As for needing status updates, launch the new QProcess in a separate thread and let that thread do the waiting.

Comment: made some edits to my code... tried what I think was right and got an error... Tried a couple ways with no luck

Comment: @John: what did you try? the following shoudl work: `connect(r, SIGNAL(finished(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)), this, SLOT(updateExit(int,QProcess::ExitStatus)));` with `void updateExit(int exitCode, QProcess::ExitStatus exitStatus);`

Comment: @John Studio - Post code if you want it solved quickly.  The easier it is for us to compile the code the quicker you're likely to have an answer.